# Object Serialization and Deserialization for XML and JSON in Ruby (library)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I am looking for a way to serialize/deseialize an object from its xml/json representation.

I am not concerned about xml namespaces.

Is there anything in Ruby which allows me to do:

```
class Person
   attr :name, true
   attr :age, true
   attr :sex, true
end

person_xml =
"<Person>
  <name>Some Name</name>
  <age>15</age>
  <sex>Male</male>
</Person>"

// and then do
p = person_xml.deserialize(Person.class)
// or something of that sort
```

Coming from a .Net background, I am looking for something which lets me consume/dispatch objects from restful web services.

How do you consume webservices in rails? (xml and json). Using xpath/active resource seems a bit too verbose (even for a .Net person)

**Using ruby 1.9.x, Rails 3.x**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Rails, Rails (via ActiveSupport) already provides a way to serialize/deserialize objects in YAML, XML and JSON.

For example

```
class Post
  attr_accessor :title
  attr_accessor :body
end

post = Post.new.tap do |p|
  p.title = "A title"
  p.body = "A body"
end

post.to_yaml
# => "--- !ruby/object:Post \nbody: A body\ntitle: A title\n"

post.to_json
# => => "{\"body\":\"A body\",\"title\":\"A title\"}"
```

If you are using ActiveRecord models, then Rails knowns how to serialize/deserialize them.

I wrote an article about [serializing and deserializing objects in Ruby using JSON](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/). Here's the documentation about the [serialization features of ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html).

Comment: What about using it outside of rails? We need to consume a couple of different webservices and wanted to deserialize the resonses to objects so that we could easily manipulate them.

Comment: You don't need Rails. If you include ActiveSupport as requirement, you can take advantage of almost the same features. Otherwise, simply use the JSON library alone.

Comment: I am specifically looking for a way to deserialize to an object.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. The decode method returns a hash. I am looking for something to which gives me an object of a given class.

Comment: You should implement that feature. Otherwise use YAML. `YAML.dump` && `YAML.load`.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider [roar gem](https://github.com/trailblazer/roar)

**Rendering**

```
song = Song.new(title: "Medicine Balls")
SongRepresenter.new(song).to_json #=> {"title":"Medicine Balls"}
```

**Parsing**

```
song = Song.new(title: "Medicine Balls")
SongRepresenter.new(song).from_json('{"title":"Linoleum"}')
song.title #=> Linoleum
```